# Why ExportToTIFF() gets TIFFs without pyramids?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, export, image-pyramids

What I want to do is to add layers (which are TIFF files) one by one to the current MXD file, and export the MXD in TIFF format. It lacks pyramids however now with the way I code.

[image: it says it lacks pyramids]

Here is my code, and I have put remarks on lines that I think are with problems.

```py
import arcpy,os
folder = r"C:\Users\Cl\Documents\PJ_50years\coding test\19720725_L1\Composites"
outdir = r"C:\Users\Cl\Documents\PJ_50years\coding test\19720725_L1\CIR"
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
images = arcpy.ListRasters("*","tif")
for image in images:
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(image)
    print(addLayer)
    ##take the current opened mxd file
    mdx = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
#######################
    ###this is the line I think there might be some problems
    df2 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
#######################
    ##add one layer to it
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df2, addLayer)
    ##save the mxd as a new one
    mdx.save()
    ##export the mxd to tiff file
    name2 = os.path.join(outdir,image[0:12]+"CIR.tif")
#######################
###this is the line I think there might be some problems
#######################   arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,name2,data_frame=df2,df_export_width=6000,df_export_height=4500,resolution=72)
    ##remove the layer from the current open mxd so next tiff could be exported without being affected
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df):
            print(lyr.name)
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)
```

[image]

while I tried such code to do each file individually, it does work as expected.

```py
import arcpy
#with one composite file open
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
mxd.save()
outdir = r"C:\Users\Cl\Documents\PJ_50years\coding test\19720725_L1\CIR"
name2 = os.path.join(outdir,"CIR.tif")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,name2,df_export_width=6000,df_export_height=4500,resolution=72)

for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df):
        print(lyr.name)
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)
```

[image]
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Build Pyramids tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-pyramids.htm) to add pyramids to your output tiff:

```
arcpy.BuildPyramids_management(name2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The step shall be done at the end of all coding right? I tried but it's still blue. Any clue what might be wrong? Thanks